# Service status plugin

Tags: plugins

Sup guys. I need a service status Widget that shows when a service of another system is down or not. Like 1.1.1.1:8080 is on/offline. Do you know a plugin for that, my google search wasn't that successful.

Answer (score 0):

Found this one on the official wp plugin list
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/atr-server-status/